# Energy estimate of linear wave equation.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

This is a question coming to me when I was reading Qian Wang's Lectures on Nonlinear Wave Equation. Link below:
http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/wangq1/Lecture_notes/nonlinear_wave_9.pdf

Let $\square_g:=\partial_t^2-g^{ij}\partial_i\partial_j$, where $g$ is a $C^\infty$ symmetric matrix function on $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and is elliptic in the sense that there exist constants $0<\lambda\leq\Lambda<\infty$ s.t. for any $(t,x)\in[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$\lambda|\xi|^2\leq g^{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\leq\Lambda|\xi|^2,\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
(I guess equivalently here we can assume $g$ is a Riemannian metric for each time $t\in [0,T]$. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!)

A lemma in page 18 says the following,

For any $u\in C^2([0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n)$, there holds
$$\|\partial u(t,\bullet)\|_{L^2}\leq C_0(\|\partial u(0,\bullet)\|_{L^2}+\int_0^t\|\square_gu(\tau,\bullet)\|_{L^2}d\tau)\exp{(C_1\int_0^t\sum_{i,j}\|\partial g^{ij}(\tau,\bullet)\|_{L^2}d\tau)},$$
for all $t\in [0,T]$, where $C_0,C_1>0$ are dependent only on the ellipticity constants $\lambda,\Lambda$.

The notation $|\partial f|^2=|\partial_t f|^2+|\partial_x f|^2$, where $|\partial_x f|^2=|\partial_1 f|^2+\cdots+|\partial_n f|$, for $f=f(t,x)$

In the proof, an energy functional is defined as the following,
$$E(t):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(|\partial_t u|^2+g^{ij}\partial_i u\partial_j u)dx.$$

The whole proof makes sense to me except for the reason why $E(t)$ is well-defined, i.e., why the integral defining $E(t)$ converges.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: How is it used in the proof of the lemma? It's possible that its convergence is not necessary, only its existence on $[0,+\infty]$ (non negativity)

Comment: @Ninad Munshi. Hi, I did not quite get your comment here. Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by its existence on $[0,\infty](non negativity)$?